# Selenium Unable to click the button when searched by XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to search for an element of class "itemavailable" in a table. If its present then click it if not go to the next row and search again in a column.

Here is the HTML code.

[image]

My code to search is here click is here. I have calculated the rows and column and also constructed the FinalXpath

```
for t_row in range(2, (num_rows)):
    for t_col in range (3, 4):
        FinalXPath = before_XPath + str(t_row) + aftertd_XPath + str(t_col) + aftertr_XPath + "[@class='itemavailable']" 
        print(FinalXPath)
        try:
            if driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"FinalXPath"):
                print("found")
                avslot = driver.find_element_by_xpath(FinalXPath)
                avslot.click()
                slot_found = True
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("not matched")
            pass
```

The output is as follows.

```
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[3]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[4]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[5]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[6]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[7]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[8]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[9]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
//*[@id='slotsGrid']/tbody/tr[10]/td[3][@class='itemavailable']
not matched
```

there is a match but not sure why its passing it.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: No wont be able to share the page, sorry

Comment: As it is now, your question does not meet the minimal reproducible example standards.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best or the most optimized solution, but I would use the `find_elements_by_xpath` function (plural), which returns a list.
If the list is not empty, you can click on the first element. Using this method, you can avoid using `NoSuchElementException`.

```
if len(results) > 0
    results[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you said, you only need to find elements with the class `itemavailable` in a given table and if the table structure is like you showthen it will be easier to use a search by id and class name:

```py
grid = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'slotsGrid')
items = grid.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'itemavalible')

for item in items:
     item.click()
```

Your table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-grid">
        <table class="masterTable table table-narrow" id="slotsGrid">
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="masterTableLeftHeader">9:00</td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemavalible">
                        <span class="buttonwrapper"><a href="http://" target="_blank">item-1</a></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemavalible">
                        <span class="buttonwrapper"><a href="http://" target="_blank">item-2</a></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="masterTableLeftHeader">9:00</td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemavalible">
                        <span class="buttonwrapper"><a href="http://" target="_blank">item-3</a></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                    <td class="itemnotavalible">...</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```